# upside down question mark insert statement

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I have a table with a column `somecolumn` of type `NCLOB`

If I do an insert using sql developer I am able to insert Cyrillic and other character set and view the data.

If I run the same statement from .net, I get `upside down ? mark`.

As I am able to insert from sql developer, I assume that this is not an issue with NLS character set.

How can I insert this character set correctly?

Comment: From my experiences, whenever a foreign character shows up as a question mark or box, it is most likely not encoded correctly. I don't have oracle at my disposal so I can't test this right now but when you insert into the database from .NET, try to ensure that the value is unicode encoded.

Comment: @TomA: The foreign characters are in a `StringBuilder` instance and a `.ToString()` is done on it before it is sent down to the method that does the insert

Comment: It will be useful if you can post the relevant .NET code that writes the `NCLOB`.

Comment: @jbluedelta I don't think StringBuilder is causing this. It is hard for me to extract the exact issue without your code, maybe you can share it as sstan mentioned? How do you insert into the database? My guess is that  .NET or whatever DB driver you are using is encoding the string into bytes and then decoding them back into string before insertion. If it does in fact encodes/decodes and it is using a non-unicode encoding then this issue can occur.

Comment: To test this, you can print out your StringBuilder.ToString() to see if the characters are as expected. My guess is that they will be correct. Then, try encoding the string to bytes then decode the bytes back to string, using a non-unicode encoding. Then print the result (or save to file). Does it show the weird characters or the excepted ones? If they do show up as weird characters then you know the insert is doing something similar underneath the hood. If that is the case, then you need to figure out a way to force the insert to encode to unicode (especially since you are using NCLOB).

Comment: Certain multi-byte characters might not get stored properly in the database. Please run a select query and please check whether the record had got inserted correct in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set one environment variable on client side.

```
Set ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE to TRUE
```

This can be permanently set in system environment variables or can be temporarily set for the session in .NET code.

If we have to set this in .NET for the current session, use following statement in your .NET code -

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE", "TRUE");
```